# Jasny's bootstrap file upload plugin - how do I handle file?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, file-upload

I'm trying to use [Jasny's file upload plugin](http://jasny.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#fileupload). The plugin appears to be working fine except I am unable to access the actual file so it can be placed into the correct directory. The only thing I ever see is the blob getting set as the thumbnail from inside the console, but no way to access it. Here is what I have so far:

```
[HTML]:
<form action="#" class="member_settings" id="member_settings" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="text" name="member_name" class="span12 m-wrap" value="{{ @user_info.member_name }}" placeholder="Company Name" rel="tooltip" title="" data-placement="bottom" data-original-title="Company Name" >
    <input type="text" name="member_email" class="span12 m-wrap" value="{{ @user_info.member_email }}" placeholder="Email Address" rel="tooltip" title="" data-placement="bottom" data-original-title="Email Address">       
    <div class="fileupload fileupload-new" data-provides="fileupload">
        <div class="fileupload-new thumbnail" >
           <img src="{{ @avatar }}" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="fileupload-preview fileupload-exists thumbnail" style="max-width: 150px; max-height: 150px; line-height: 20px;"></div>
        <div class="span12">
           <span class="btn btn-file"><span class="fileupload-new">Select New Image</span>
           <span class="fileupload-exists">Change</span>
           <input type="file" id="file" name="file" class="default" /></span>
           <a href="#" class="btn fileupload-exists" data-dismiss="fileupload">Remove</a>
        </div>
     </div>
     <div id="update_user_settings" class="btn green pull-right" style="margin:2px;"><i class="icon-check"></i> Update Profile</div>    
</form>

[JS]:
<script>
$('#update_user_settings').click(function() {
    $('.fileupload').fileupload({
        url: '/api/upload/profile_img/{{ @SESSION.portal_id }}'
    }); 
    var post_url = "/api/update/user/details";
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: post_url,
        data: $('#member_settings').serialize(),    
        dataType: "html"    
    }); 
});
</script>
```

My problem is that nothing is getting sent to the url. I don't see anything in the console when I submit.

The only tutorials I've seen use the entire fileuploader inside of a form, but what I'm trying to do is allow the user to make all desired changes and then apply them.

Is there something I'm missing?